# Training acoustic model for CMU Sphinx using Finite state grammar (JSGF)

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I need to train my own acoustic model. On the official wiki, this process is described for ngramm models in DMP format, but I need to use a (grammar) language model provided in JSGF format. Is there a such possibility? And if so, could you give a tutorial on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifications are minimial. Open psdecode.pl script in the installed location or in scripts and change

```
-lm => $ST::DEC_CFG_LANGUAGEMODEL,
```

to

```
-jsgf => "/full/path/to/jsgf/file",
```

Comment: Thanks! but.. can i set this thing anywhere in config files? I'm working on adapting simon for using sphinx, and on the basis of this problem, I can not afford to change the script on the user's machine.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do it in the configuration files. If you want to suggest some new feature to be included into sphinxtrain, you are welcome to do so https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=1904&atid=301904