# Using JSGF grammar instead of DMP language model (use -jsgf instead of -lm) in CMU Sphinx (pocketsphinx)

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I need to train CMU Sphinx offline in my android app. I downloaded [this](https://github.com/Kaljurand/Inimesed) project that use this parameter but when I start it I have this error: `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001c (code=1)`. This error I also have when Sphinx can not find the accoustic model. I found answer on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260151/training-acoustic-model-for-cmu-sphinx-using-finite-state-grammar-jsgf), but it is does not work for me. What I am doing wrong, can anybody can provide me any tutorial, or a good answer?

So the question is how to use `.jsgf` files istead of `.DMP` files as language model for Pocketsphinx like it used in Recognizer task in Inimesed project?

Comment: Provide the file pocketsphinx.log created on your device

Comment: Here is the Log:

NFO: acmod.c(242): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/ee.ioc.phon.android.inimesed/files/hmm/et_ee/16000/feat.params
INFO: feat.c(684): Initializing feature stream to type: 's2_4x', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 84: Acoustic model definition is not specified neither with -mdef option nor with -hmm

I can provide whole file if needed

Comment: This error means that you didn't put the data files into proper location. Check what folder should contain the model in sources (-hmm option)

Answer (score 3):

If CMU Sphinx works similarly on Android and on Windows, the following may help:

http://www.aiaioo.com/cms/index.php?id=28
http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/k.vdeemter/pages/teaching/NLP/practicals/JSGFGrammar.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/

Example JSGF file:

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar hello;
public <command> = ( open | close ) ( computer | window | music | note );
```

Save the above grammar in a text file called "hello.gram", then run sphinx with:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -hmm hub4wsj_sc_8k -jsgf hello.gram -dict hub4.5000.dic
```